# Type safe aliases from sealed traits

Tags: scala, alias, traits

Is there a way I can alias a sealed trait in such a way that it would provide type safety?  I know I could write a case class or resort to type classes, however those solutions are overkill I'd like to do.

A trivial example illustrating it:

```
type Lon = Double
type Lat = Double

def lonLatPair(lon:Lon, lat:Lat):(Lon, Lat) = (lon, lat) 

val someLon:Lon = 1.2
val someLat:Lat = 3.4

lonLatPair(someLon, someLat) // Success!
lonLatPair(someLat, someLon) // Dismal failure in the form of a type error
```

Answer (score 2):

You can declare implicit classes instead:

```
implicit class Lon(val value: Double) extends AnyVal
implicit class Lat(val value: Double) extends AnyVal
```

Implicit classes have the advantage that you can use a double any time a `Lon` or a `Lat` is required — this allows your assignment to work, but this may be too permissive depending on your use cases.

The `extends AnyVal` part basically means that, most of the time, there is no runtime overhead to using `Lon` or `Lat` instead of the native type `Double`.

Alternatively, you can use the “unboxed new type” technique using Scalaz ([example](http://timperrett.com/2012/06/15/unboxed-new-types-within-scalaz7/)) or shapeless ([example](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/shapeless/examples/newtype.scala)).